# iPhone 5 magnetometer data calibration

Tags: ios, iphone, magnetometer

I captured raw magnetometer data on the iPhone 5 by accident, and I actually require the calibrated data. The problem is that I can't go and recapture the data I originally got. Does anyone know what the iPhone's hard bias (device bias) calibration values are and how I can apply them to my data to get a similar output to what the iPhone would have given me?

Alternatively what is the best approach to calibrate for the device bias? I don't care about soft bias in my measurements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone needs calibration data not to calibrate for the internal sensor (that is always accounted for, even in "raw" data, which actually isn't as raw as you might think). It is actually to calibrate for external factors that might disrupt or interfere with the Earth's natural magnetic field, like high voltage power lines, or steel beams overhead. The iPhone creates a 3D distortion map of the field (which is why the compass app asks you to make a figure eight) to offset these external influences.

Finally, even if you could recreate the exact distortions, Apple provides no way to peek into their black-box filtering, let alone apply your own distortion map to their data. So no, you cannot recompute the calibrated data after the fact.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I wasn't aware that the raw data wasn't completely raw. That should allow me to perform the processing I want.

Comment: It's raw in the fact that they don't do any filtering over time, or incorporation of other sensor data, but it isn't raw voltage readings or something that low-level. It's definitely calibrated for the specific magnetometer offsets and perhaps other characteristics, like internal temperature (I'm not sure about that one for the magnetometer, actually, but I am for the gyro).